# How to calculate similarity between two arrays?

Tags: algorithm, similarity, cosine-similarity

I have two arrays like these: a1=[8,6,4,8,8,9] , a2=[7,3,8,4,3,9,9,5,8,3,5,8] . They may contain different number of integers that can be repeated. How can I calculate similarity between these? Which metric should I use?

UPDATE: numbers represent vote from 1 to 10. Users vote items in one specific category. We don't know items they have been voted. We only know that these items are belong to the same category. So we have arrays of votes in category. The problem is how we could calculate similarity between these users.

Comment: do you mean that the entire first array should be found in the second one?

Comment: @ZachiShtain, thay can be completely different. These two arrays represent votes of two users for a specific category of items.

Comment: If they represent votes of two users, shouldn't they be the same size?

Comment: @ZachiShtain, nope. One user can vote for 3 times and another for 30.

Comment: I think you should explain your question better, there is no sense in comparing how to users voted for two different items, regardless of the number of items they've voted for

Comment: What do the numbers represent?  Are they somehow *intensities* (so that a 4 present in a1 and a 5 present in a2 should be considered more similar than a 1 present in a1 and a 50 present in a2) or are they *categories* (so that any pair of different numbers carries the same weight)?

Comment: @ZachiShtain updated question.

Comment: @j_random_hacker, updated question.

Comment: @alex.krestin: It's still totally unclear whether the votes are *categories* or *intensities*.  Is a 10 vote similar to a 9 vote or not?

Comment: @j_random_hacker, are intensities. So yes, 10 is similar to 9

Comment: OK, in that case my answer is useless.  I'll delete it.

Comment: Which metric to use rather depends on how you define "similarity." You could sum the array and divide by the number of votes, which gives you the average vote per user. Or compute the median. Or give the average *and* standard deviation to tell you how consistent the user is. If you don't know what you want to measure, we can't tell you how to measure it.

Comment: @JimMischel, average is useless because if we have the first user which have voted 30 items and have average vote 8 and the second user which have voted only one item with 8, we can't say that they are similar. That is the problem. I need similarity value from 0 to 1 at the end. With metric I intended the algorithm which should I use. Like cosine-similarity (I understand that I need to modify some of them in order to fit it to my case).

Comment: Jim Mischel is right. There are infinitely many ways in which you could compute "similarity" between two arbitrary arrays of integers, and they're all "right". In general: take three arrays of integers. You need to be able to explain which two are most similar and which two are least similar, at least in broad terms, before we can hope to give you any kind of answer here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Treat your votes as random samples

If you really don't know what they voted for, the only thing you have is the distribution of votes. I.e., you have two samples from two distributions and you need to evaluate the difference between the distributions.

The simplest approach would be to count the number of times the user gave a given vote, i.e., convert `[8,6,4,8,8,9]` to `[0,0,0,1,0,1,0,3,9,0]` (i.e., 3 votes of 8 means 3 in the 8th position). Now your vectors have the same length and you can use cosine similarity.

### Fuzzy your data

If you do **not** have much data, i.e., you really need to compare people who voted 1-2 times, you can try "fuzzying the votes", i.e., treating a vote for `8` as 1/2 vote for 8, and 1/4 votes for each of 7 and 9. E.g., your vectors `[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]` and `[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0]` will become `[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.33,0.66]` and `[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.25,0.5,0.25]`.

This is equivalent to using an "unusual" dot product: instead of the simple `(v,u)=sum_i(v_i*u_i*)`, use `(Av,u)=sum_ij(a_ij*v_i*u_j)` where `A` is an almost diagonal matrix ([e.g.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix), `a_ii=4`, `a_ij=1` if `|i-j|=1`, `a_ij=0` otherwise). Then the new cosine similarity is then defined as

```
CS(u,v)=arccos( (Av,u) / sqrt( (Av,v) * (Au,u) ) )
```

For the [tridiagonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix) example 
above, the formula looks like:

```
(Av,u) = 4*sum(v_i,u_i) + sum(v_i,u_{i-1}) + (v_i,u_{i+1})
```

### Use Stats

If you **do** have a lot of data, i.e., every person has votes every number at least 5 times (i.e., each length 10 vector has all components >=5), then you can use [Chi-squared test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test) or, [better yet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neyman-Pearson_lemma), [Likelihood-ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood-ratio_test).

### recommender system

You should specify which coordinates match (if you, as I suspect, doing a recommender system).
E.g., if user 1 votes are `[3]` and user 2 votes are `[4,5]`, you need to know whether score `3` is for the same object as score `4` or `5` or for an entirely different object.

Comment: it seems very similar that what I need. You're right, we can decompose vectors to the same size. But if we calculate the cosine similarity for vectors: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1] and [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0] the result will be 0, while I aspect something like 0,9. Are there any other solution?

Comment: it wasn't I. Some people can't understand the question and downvote it.

Comment: And what about if we use soft cosine similarity? Supose that we have similarity matrix between votes. Like 10:9 as 0,9 or 6:4 as 0,8 . But I can't understand how can I apply this matrix to vectors.

Comment: The case problem is that I don't know individual object's score, so I can't say if [3] is the same object of [4] or [5]. They may be completely different objects. The same is only category (i.e. "science" for  science news). I try to understand your answer... Can you explain it in some example please?

Comment: About "unusual" dot product

Comment: I added an example, but I cannot explain matrix operations in this answer. You should get [a good book](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/804716/37092).

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestions and time spent for me! I solved the problem with fuzzying based on vote similarity and applying Pearson correlation. It seems to give excellent result :)